# i'm using nest js and mongodb with prisma and i want to send the district data in form of array but have facing some problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

error is : Type 'districttype' is not assignable to type 'UserCreateroleInput | Enumerable'

here is my authdto file. in authdto i'm taking district type. for the type of districtype i'm create a district.dto and here is my auth dto and distric dto

```
export class AuthDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string;
  @IsEmail()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  email: string;
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  password: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  distric?: districtypes[]

  @IsBoolean()
  @Type(() => Boolean)
  isActive?: boolean;
}
```

in before code you see my distric.dto file in my distric dto i'm taking sum types for distric
here is distric.dto file

```
import { IsBoolean } from "class-validator"

export interface districtypes{
    
    is_udaipur:boolean;
    is_jaipur:boolean
    is_bikaner:boolean
    is_chittor:boolean
}
```

and i want to send the distric data in array form in database but face some error. here is my auth .service file

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService,
    private jwt: JwtService,
    private config: ConfigService,
  ) {}
  async signUp(dto: AuthDto) {
      const hash = await argon.hash(dto.password);
      console.log('dto',dto);
      const user = await this.prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          firstName: dto.firstName,
          lastName: dto.lastName,
          mobile: dto.mobile,
          email: dto.email,
          district: dto.district,   //i'm facing this problem on this place the error is 
                              "Types'districttypes[]' is not assignable to type 'UserCreateroleInput | 
                                                                    Enumerable<string>'."
          hash,
          isActive: dto.isActive,
        },
      });
            return this.signInToken(
        user.id,
        user.email,
      );
    } 
  }
```

Comment: you seem to have a typo `distric` (in `AuthDto`) vs `district` (in `AuthService`), we'd also need to see the schema for the `prisma.user` - it looks like (as the error suggests) you're trying to assign an array of districts to something declared to be an array of strings